# ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig being called after Page_Load and Page_PreRender

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a routing setup which is doing this Rewrite:

```
<rule name="some Rule" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
    <match url="*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="/folder/*" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/folder/details.aspx?url={PATH_INFO}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

And I also have this:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxUrlLength="256" />
```

I have a bot calling to an invalid url, something like:

http://localhost:53649/route/Somefolder-Heres/W-ithsom-tet-Text-(An%C3%83%C6%92%C3%86%E2%80%99%C3%83%E2%80%A0%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%E2%84%A2%C3%83%C6%92%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%20%C3%83/MoreTExt-(%C2%A2%C3%A2%E2%80%9A%C2%AC%C3%A2%E2%80%9E%C2%A2%C3%83%C6%92%C3%86%E2%80%99%C3%83%C2%A2%C3%A2%E2%80%9A%C2%AC%C3%82%20%C3%83%C6%92%C3%82%C2%A2%C3%83%C2%A2%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C5%A1%C3%82%C2%AC%C3%83%C2%A2%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C5%BE%C3%82%C2%A2%C3%83%C6%92%C3%86%E2%80%99%C3%83%E2%80%A0%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%E2%84%A2%C3%83%C6%92%C3%82%C2%A2%C3%83%C2%A2%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C5%A1%C3%82%C2%AC%C3%83%E2%80%A6%C3%82%C2%A1%C3%83%C6%92%C3%86%E2%80%99%C3%83%C2%A2%C3%A2%E2%80%9A%C2%AC%C3%85%C2%A1%C3%83%C6%92%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C5%A1%C3%83%E2%80%9A%C3%82%C2%A1stasis)/someUrl(An%C3%83%C6%92%C3%86%E2%80%99%C3%83%E2%80%A0%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%E2%84%A2%C3%83%C6%92%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%20%C3%83%C2%A2%C3%A2%E2%80%9A%C2%AC%C3%A2%E2%80%9E%C2%A2%C3%83%C6%92%C3%86%E2%80%99%C3%83%C2%A2%C3%A2%E2%80%9A%C2%AC%C3%82%20%C3%83%C6%92%C3%82%C2%A2%C3%83%C2%A2%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C5%A1%C3%82%C2%AC%C3%83%C2%A2%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C5%BE%C3%82%C2%A2%C3%83%C6%92%C3%86%E2%80%99%C3%83%E2%80%A0%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%E2%84%A2%C3%83%C6%92%C3%82%C2%A2%C3%83%C2%A2%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C5%A1%C3%82%C2%AC%C3%83%E2%80%A6%C3%82%C2%A1%C3%83%C6%92%C3%86%E2%80%99%C3%83%C2%A2%C3%A2%E2%80%9A%C2%AC%C3%85%C2%A1%C3%83%C6%92%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C5%A1%C3%83%E2%80%9A%C3%82%C2%A1stasis)/

So ASP.NET throws this exception

> The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured
>   maxUrlLength value.
>
> at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
>
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)

The problem I have is that the `ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig` from ASP.NET is being called **after** my Page_Load and Page_PreRender. I could explain a little more about what I'm doing here but my question is:

Why ASP.NET is validating the URL after my page is executed? it makes no sense, why it wastes time processing the page, shouldn't make more sense to do that before? Is there any way to change this behavior?

I uploaded a demo on Github:
So you can download this solution https://github.com/kblok/StackOverflowExamples/tree/master/AspNetDemoProject

And break [In the page load](https://github.com/kblok/StackOverflowExamples/blob/master/AspNetDemoProject/AspNetDemoProject/Demos/routingDemo.aspx.cs#L14) and then in the 
[Error module](https://github.com/kblok/StackOverflowExamples/blob/master/AspNetDemoProject/AspNetDemoProject/App_Code/ErrorModule.cs#L18). You'll see that the PageLoad is being hit first.

Comment: Looking at this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx#Life%20Cycle%20Stages it seems that `Validate the request` is the first step executed even before URL Mapping, raising `BeginRequest` event etc. Are you sure `Page_Load` is executed first? And are you sure that its getting executed for the SAME request?

Comment: Yes @VivekAthalye I have an error module, so I added 3 breakpoints: in Load, in PreRender and in that Module, The error is being reached after Load and PreRender. I'll try to upload a piece of code

Comment: Is there a possibility that your `Page_Load` and any other events are getting executed properly resulting in some kind of `Response.Redirect` and at the beginning of new request its causing error?

Comment: Yes, I'm redirecting on Page_Load, because the URL is invalid, and because of that the Server.TransferRequest in my error module (called after the page load) is not working. I would expect the page to fail before my page load.

Comment: @VivekAthalye demo project uploaded

Comment: I downloaded your code from Github. It has too many files. If possible keep only minimum required files. I had to comment out few lines in `Site.Master` `Global.asax` and exclude some of the files to get default page of AspNetDemoProject displayed. Also I had to set `/langversion:default` as I don't have latest version of .NET. Once default page was displayed, I added breakpoint on `Page_Load` (which is empty) and `OnError` in ErrorModule.

Comment: When I refreshed default page w/o passing any params, breakpoint @`Page_Load` was hit; not the other. When I accessed the URL you have given above, breakpoint @`OnError` was hit with the same error mentioned by you, and the breakpoint @`Default.aspx.cs` was **NOT** hit. Btw, I could not find `Response.Redirect` code in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the points that you have mentioned in the comments what I understand is

1. Your page `details.aspx` is getting accessed with query string param `url=<path with unicode characters>`.
2. In the `Page_Load` your code checks the request, finds out that its invalid and redirects user to new URL.
3. And THIS NEW URL is longer than the max allowed length so you get `The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value.`

The lengh of the original request URL is within limits so there is no error before `Page_Load`.

Comment: It's not that sir, I've just updated the question with a demo project.